# How can I modify the type of file that my client-side GET calling method returns?

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, media

I'm trying to implement a GET functionality in my springboot project but I'm pretty new to backend development and I'm struggling with debugging. I'm choosing a File and passing it as a MultipartFile to the server through a POST call, compressing it, storing it in a database and then, for the output, I'm decompressing and sending it back through a GET call for it to be displayed. I tested the server side through Postman and it works just fine (the image/video is being displayed properly in the body section of the app) so the error must be caused somewhere in the client side. The error code I'm getting is:

```
Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Unrecognized file signature!
```

And is caused on this line, when I'm creating the JavaFX Media object for the file, so that it can be displayed in a MediaView:

```
Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

I'm guessing that it's because the file is in the .tmp format at the end of the client-side get call method, but I don't know how to retrieve the original format and convert the file to it. This is the method that makes the GET call in the client:

```
public File getFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String url = getServer()+ "secure/" + store.accessStore().getUsername() + "/file/" + fileName;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, byte[].class);
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBody());
        File file = File.createTempFile("temp", ".tmp");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return file;
    }
```

Could you help?